# Need help linking mapKit annotation to CollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, uicollectionview, mapkit

I'm building an app in swift that has a collection view and a map view on the same page. The user can scroll through the collection view to see offers (this is the purpose of the app) and the map view is populated with annotation pins displaying the physical location of the offers on the map.

My issue is that i'm finding it hard to link the collection view cell to the correct annotation.

I add the the annotations to the map as below:

```
for location in self.queryDataMapAnnotations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
            annotation.subtitle = location["distance"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }
```

I then can scroll through the collection view cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        // Connect cell to the linked annotation 

        // ** This links to a random annotation, but not the correct one - need help on this please ** 
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[row], animated: true)

    }
```

if any one could help me on how to link the collection view to the correct map annotation, I would be most helpful. I only know swift (a little) so would appreciate help in that language. Thanks

Comment: Is your purpose to highlight annotation when collection cell is **tapped**? Because currently you call `selectAnnotation()` in the wrong collection view dataSource method.

Comment: No, the purpose is to select the annotation as the user scrolls through the collection view. So when the user scrolls to the 1st collection view cell, the corresponding annotation is selected and show the title and subtitle. Then this continues as the user scrolls to the 2nd cell,3rd etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want active map annotations to change as you scroll, and you want to consider vertically centred collection cell to be the currently displayed — here is the way I came up with.

**NOTE: I didn't test it, it's just the basic idea**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView is UICollectionView {
        let collectionViewCenter = CGPoint(x: collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 + collectionView.contentOffset.x, y: collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2 + collectionView.contentOffset.y)
        let centredCellIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: collectionViewCenter)

        guard let path = centredCellIndexPath else {
            // There is no cell in the center of collection view (you might want to think what you want to do in this case)
            return
        }

        if let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations.first {
            // Ignore if correspondent annotation is already selected
            if selectedAnnotation.isEqual(self.mapView.annotations[path.row]) {
                self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[path.row], animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This performs the same function as having the 'selectAnnotation' in cellForItemAt delegate method. The issue is that the annotation selected with both your solution and mine, is incorrect. so when cell 1 is in view, annotation 3 is selected. Scrolling to cell 2 selects annotation 5 (random examples but you get the picture. This is because the annotations and the cell data are misaligned - so I need to create a way to link the two in sync, but I'm not sure how to. Any thoughts on this are most welcome. Thanks again

Comment: I actually figured my way of doing it was wrong. Please check updated answer and give it a chance.

Comment: @StevenH It might actually need one more modification for this line: `let collectionViewCenter = CGPoint(x: collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 + collectionView.contentOffset.x, y: collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2 + collectionView.contentOffset.y)`. Not sure, can;t test here right now.

Comment: Hi, just testing your method now. The line 'let centredCellIndexPath = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint: collectionViewCenter];' gets an error saying 'expected ',' separator. Also i'm not quite sure how to fully implement it - do i just add scrollViewDidScroll() to one of the collection view delegate methods? Sorry for stupid question, i'm a beginner! Any further help much appreciated.

Comment: i've updated a couple of elements to Swift 3 (as that was causing issues). Now have aa problem with if self.mapView.annotations[centredCellIndexPath.row] != mapView.selectedAnnotations.first {
                self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[centredCellIndexPath.row], animated: true)
            }
its saying 'value of type [indexPath?] has no type 'row'

Comment: @StevenH Re: scrollViewDidScroll() — yes, just add it to the same place you defined `collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt indexPath:)` at. `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can use delegate methods of scroll view.

Re: your new errors — check the updated version.

Comment: ok so no errors, but still doesn't work. i'm using scrollViewDidScroll(collectionView) within the collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt indexPath:)  delegate method - I'm not 100% sure the parameter is correct. I think we're super close though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @StevenH You don'thave to call `scrollViewDidScroll()` yourself. Just setting `collectionView.delegate = self` (I think you did it) is enough. When you scroll your collection view — `scrollViewDidScroll()` should be automatically called and select annotation corresponding to the cell that's currently vertically centred.

Comment: ah ok, sorry about that! So the scroll is being detected, I added some print(test") code in to check. But the annotations are not being selected i'm afraid. the code runs, it seems to detect the scroll on the collectionView but no annotation is highlighted. Any ideas no next steps? thanks again for your help with this, i've been trying to work this out for a month..

Comment: @StevenH Could you put more `print()` messages inside `if` and `guard` blocks, so that I see at what step it fails?

Comment: Just did this. It doesn't print inside the guard block, or the any of the following blocks.

Comment: the self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[(path?.row)!], animated: true)  functions if i move it outside of the if let selectedAnnotation look, but it selects the wrong annotation as i scroll through the collection view. again, thanks for your help, really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar functionality, User scrolls the collectionview which displays list of nearby deals and mapview's camera should shift to the location of the currently visible deal in the collection view, following describes my implementation

```
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
        /* set pagewidth to collectionview cell width*/
        let pageWidth = collectionView.bounds.width 
        let currentOffset : Float = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        let targetOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.memory.x)
        var newTargetOffset : Float = 0.0

        if targetOffset > currentOffset {
            newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset/(pageWidth)) * pageWidth
            /* if colelctionview swipped right increment the curentlyVisibleIndex*/
       //dealList is array of Model objects used to populate the 
              //CollectionView
            if currentlyVisibleIndex != (dealList.count - 1) {
                currentlyVisibleIndex += 1
            }
        }
        else{
            newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset/(pageWidth)) * pageWidth
            /*if collectionview swipped left decrement the currentlyVisibleCounter */
            if currentlyVisibleIndex !=  0 {
                currentlyVisibleIndex -= 1
            }
        }
        if newTargetOffset < 0{
            newTargetOffset = 0
        }else if  newTargetOffset > Float(scrollView.contentSize.width){
            newTargetOffset = Float(scrollView.contentSize.width)
        }
        targetContentOffset.memory.x = CGFloat(currentOffset)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(newTargetOffset), y: 0), animated: true)

        moveCameraToDealLocation()
        // re initialise the annotations of mapView
        let annotationArray = mapBoxViewController.mapView.annotations
        mapBoxViewController.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotationArray)
        mapBoxViewController.mapView.addAnnotations(annotationArray)
    }

    func moveCameraToDealLocation(){
        mapBoxViewController.moveMapViewCameraToLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dealList[currentlyVisibleIndex].eventLatitude, longitude: dealList[currentlyVisibleIndex].eventLongitude))
    }
```

currentlyVisibleIndex gives me the index of the currently visible deal(annotation), the function moveCameraToDealLocation moves the MapView camera to that annotation.
Do let me know if this works for you :)